# JPEG Image Binary File (HEX format) merging (QVGA / VGA)

Tags: c, image-processing, jpeg, libjpeg

I need to generate a  QVGA Image (320x 240) from RGB888. Due to memory constrain of the controller I have generated 3 JPEG images of (320 X 80). Now I need to merge these 3 (320 X 80) JPEG images to generate one complete QVGA JPEG image (320 x 240). I have Hex files for the 3 JPEG Images. Is there any C source file available to do other than OpenCV concept ???

What I have tried ?

1. Tried to Match the JPEG Header in the binary file : first half of the image is clear, remaining part is distorted.

What I'm expecting ?

1. C source file to merge the 3 or more JPEG Binary files to One.

Comment: How's the controller suddenly going to have enough memory for 3 images of 320x80 as well as a 320x240 version? JPEG files aren't hex, they are binary. How did you create the 320x80 images exactly? Did you think of making PPM files instead?

Comment: "hex files"... so you have _binary_ data for three jpeg images, and you want to _cheaply_ merge them into one complete jpeg? that might be possible *because* of how at least one mode of JPEG works (blocks, encoded in horizontal bands) but you will have to understand completely *how* JPEG works.

Comment: @Mark Setchell : 

1. Memory : Process is like *Bayer RGB --> *RGB888 --> *JPEG Encoder. The place where I'm facing memory problem is conversion from Bayer RGB to RGB888.
for that reason I'm only converting 1/3 of the Bayer RGB to RGB888 for passing to JPEG Encoder, so only 1/3 of the memory required for RGB888 data.
Final JPEG Image is compressed, so I have enough memory to hold the complete JPEG Image. 

2. Yes, JPEG Image is binary file, but HEX format.

Comment: I don't know of any software in source form that will do that for you. You could look at `jpegtran` https://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/ Or look at my answer here for links and hope all 3 of your images use the same tables https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719028/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell : Thanks for the response, I think that is not possible for now. will find a way around.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz : Thanks for your response.