# Low Level JPEG Encoding

Tags: image, jpeg, huffman-code, low-level

I am trying to implement a JPEG encoder using the lowest possible operations. It is relatively doable up to Huffman encoding where most tutorials are using pointers and binary trees to make the table and encode the image. Can someone more familiar with the JPEG standard point me in the direction of the simplest compression technique that I should try to implement with low level operations (+, -, *, shifts, loops, if statements).

I have heard there are standard Huffman tables (I can't really find one), are these typically a good idea to use? After I use a standard huffman table, how simple is it to encode a 8x8 chunk with it? I stopped here, because I didn't want to go down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Pointers are a low-level operation, something CPU hardware supports directly.  Of course, simpler sets of operations can still be Turing-complete, but perhaps much less efficiently for some problems.

Comment: There are some links in my answer here to some quite comprehensive descriptions of JPEG here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65719028/2836621

Answer (score 2):

The [standard](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf) will answer all of your questions. There are "typical" Huffman codes provided there in appendix K.3, along with the specifications for those tables. You can just hard-code those into your implementation and you will get good performance.

Since the Huffman codes are given, you would not need to implement the Huffman algorithm, which is what needs the pointers and trees you are referring to. (Not terribly complicated, so it is something you should tackle later, once you get the pre-defined codes working.)

You can just use the code table and a set of operators, which also need to include bitwise or (`|`) and bitwise and (`&`) along with the others in your list. The encoding process is simple, which is to have a bit buffer in an integer into which you accumulate code bits using the shift and or operators, and then pulling bytes from the buffer to write to the output when there are eight or more bits in the buffer.